# Got Http response code 403 while accessing this paypal API "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payouts"

Tags: paypal

I an trying to implement this paypal payout API. When i was trying to check the api it gives

```
  -data: "{"name":"AUTHORIZATION_ERROR",
   "debug_id":"27b145efd5d07","message":"Authorization error occurred.", 
  "information_link": "https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.payouts-batch/#errors"}"
```

Please suggest me this API is working for India (currency INR) or not. If it is not working then let me know alternative for this API.

Basically i want to send amount from one account to another account with the help of API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be multiple reason.

**1.** This API will need to enable by paypal.

**2. US merchants—** To enable Payouts, you can complete either of the following actions:

Contact your Account Manager or PayPal customer support.

Enable Payouts from My Account:

Log in to the Developer Dashboard and go to My Account.

Under Permissions name, locate Payouts and click the Enable link.

Click Enable, complete the form and click Submit. When you've been approved, you'll receive an email from a PayPal representative.

**3. Non-US merchants—** To enable Payouts, contact your Account Manager or PayPal customer support.

**4.** Check whether this API will be available for your country. Some countries it is not allowed to transfer  money (wallet amount) from one account to another.

For information [Click here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payouts/integrate/)

Comment: is it possible to use in india

Comment: It is not allowed in india.

Comment: How i can implement this

Comment: contact customer care for more information. Submit a request form on this url              https://www.paypal-support.com